# How to make selector from a recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, selector

I need to make day selector like in the screenshot below.

[image]

The problem is in coloring numbers. I need white numbers while they are in the circle.

I decided to do it with with 2 recyclerviews that are synchronized with each other. One recyclerview has black colored items and the other has white ones.

[image]

But there is no way to combine them together to get the desired result. Please, give me an idea of the correct implementation of this.

If it was possible to give the recyclerview view a shape of a circle, it would resolve my problem. But it seems that recyclerview doesn't have this feature.

Answer (score 0):

use Model to RecyclerView and handle state inside it. make one boolean into Model and If date gets selected make it true else make it false and notify adapter. Inside adapter, if the flag is true then make date TextBox colour white else black

```
class Model {
  String date;
  boolean isSelected;
  //....
  
  public boolean isSelected(){
    return isSelected;
  }

  public void setSelected(boolean isSelected){
    this.isSelected = isSelected;
  }
}
```

inside `onBindViewHolder()` of adapter

```
if (modelList.get(position).isSelected())
    holder.textBoxDate.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white));
else
    holder.textBoxDate.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.black));
```

for more google it "how to manage selected state in recyclerview android"

Comment: It would be too easy. I need partial coloring of symbols. As you can see in the second screenshot, the part of symbol '2' is grey inside the circle and the other part of symbol '2' is black outside the circle.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can give recycler view items's shape circle by these steps
1: Create a framelayout
2: Place cardview inside it.
3: Add  app:cardCornerRadius="150dp" in card view.
4: Add textview inside

```html
 <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"

            >
           <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:id="@+id/crd"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:cardCornerRadius="150dp">

                   <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                      android:text="4"
                       android:textColor="#000"
                       android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:id="@+id/colorBox"

                    />


        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


    </FrameLayout>
```

output would b like :
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FOFN.png)

Comment: I know the way to give a recycler's item a shape of circle. But I wonder if it possible to give a circle shape to a whole reyclerview.